# html5 localstorage not saving input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to safe a value in localstorage to use it later on other pages, but I can't quite get it to work.

My input field:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="" id="test" required />
         <span class="highlight"></span>
         <span class="bar"></span>
         <label>enter something</label>
```

My script:

```
<script>

function getStorage(type) {
  var storage = window[type + 'Storage'],
    delta = 0,
    p = document.createElement('p');

  if (!window[type + 'Storage']) return;

  if (storage.getItem('value')) {    
    p.innerHTML = type + 'Storage: ' + storage.getItem('value');
  } else {
    p.innerHTML = type + 'nothing safed';
  }

  document.querySelector('#output').appendChild(p);
}

getStorage('test');


addEvent(document.querySelector('#test'), 'keyup', function () {
  localStorage.setItem('value', this.value);
});


</script>
```

My output:

```
    <p id="output"></p>
```

Note: I'm using h5utils.js (https://java.net/projects/prototype/sources/svn/content/trunk/demosprojects/AjaxAdmin/web/h5utils.js?rev=11) to make it all work, but I can't get output. No errors in the console.

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as `window.testStorage`, so your `getStorage('test')` call will return immediately.

Comment: All I see here is a value being written to localStorage with the key "value", then you try to get values out from testStorage, which is meaningless. Call `getStorage('local')` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Will changing getStorage('test') to getStorage('local') do the trick?

Comment: Yes. See my answer :) PS Changed "safed" to "saved".

Comment: haha, thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the getStorage function passing a type of 'test', which then attempts to look up window.testStorage which doesn't exist of course.

Use...

```
getStorage('local');
```

... instead to look up localStorage.

Comment: stupid mistake, I should take a break and get some coffee. Anyway, thanks a lot!